# How to limit incorrect answers from users input?

Tags: python

I'm here with my code, here you can see it:

```
def generate_integer(level):
    score = 0
    i = 0
    false = 0
    level = int(level)
    while i != 10:

            # Choosing the numbers of digit if 1 >> 1-9 / if 2 >> 11-99 / if 3 >> 100-999
            end = 10**level-1

            # Define x and y
            x = random.randint(0,end)
            y = random.randint(0,end)
            answer = x + y

            # Users cal
            user = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
            if user == answer:
                score = score + 1
            while user != answer:
                false + 1
                print('EEE')
                user = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
            if false == 3:
                print(f'{x} + {y} = {answer}')


            i = i + 1

    print(f'score: {score}/10')
```

Let me explain: I defined false for, if user inputs the answer 3 times and all of them for that question are false, show user the answer and continue asking

Actually this code asks 10 different math questions, this is a part of my code, I'm checking if answer is not true print('EEE') and re ask it again, but if user tries 3 time and all incorrect, then I show the answer, pass that question and keep asking other questions.

If you have any ideas for re asking question, when users input was non-numerical, I'll be thankful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For starters. `false += 1` or `false = false + 1` if you aren't into the whole brevity thing. Second issue I see is that second while loop. get rid of that. The whole things should be an `if/elif/elif` block inside a single while loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def check(user_answer,correct_answer):
    for a chance in range(2):
        print("Wrong answer, try again") 
        user_answer=input('User please type your answer for the question')
        if user_answer == correct_answer:
            return 'True' # Given the Right answer
        else:
            print('Again wrong answer')
    return 'False' #Given all wrongs answers

user_answer=input('User please type your answer for the question')

correct_answer=10

if user_answer != correct_answer:
    result=check(user_answer,correct_answer)

    if result:
        print("your answer is correct")
    else:
        print("your all answers were wrong, the right answer is: ",correct_answer)

else:
    print("Perfect your answer was right in the first guess")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

You just have an indentation wrong

```
def generate_integer(level):
    score = 0
    i = 0
    false = 0
    level = int(level)
    while i != 10:

            # Choosing the numbers of digit if 1 >> 1-9 / if 2 >> 11-99 / if 3 >> 100-999
            end = 10**level-1

            # Define x and y
            x = random.randint(0,end)
            y = random.randint(0,end)
            answer = x + y

            # Users cal
            user = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
            if user == answer:
                score = score + 1
            while user != answer:
                false + 1
                print('EEE')
                user = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
                if false == 3:
                    print(f'{x} + {y} = {answer}')
                    break


            i = i + 1

    print(f'score: {score}/10')
```

Would probably work, because you want to be checking for how many times they messed up within the `while` loop.

OTHER PIECES OF ADVICE
I would also rename `false` to `num_incorrect_tries`, and replace `10**level-1` with `10**(level-1)`

You can also just for `for i in range(11)`, instead of doing a while loop, and incrementing `i`

Comment: You also want to move the `false = 0` into the loop, otherwise it won't reset between questions.

Comment: ```false += 1```. Also, reset ```false = 0``` before breaking.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is ask for the input in a separate function inside of a while True loop that only exits when it detects the input to be an integer.  In my example below the `getint` function does just that.

I made a few other minor adjustments to your function to simplify it a little as well. I have tested and can confirm it does work the way you describe.

I left some inline notes to explain where I made changes

```
import random

def getint(x,y):
    while 1:
        user = input(f'{x} + {y} = ')  # get user input
        if user.isdigit():             # check if it is an integer
            return int(user)           # return integer value
        print("Non-Integer Input Detected: Try Again")  # print Error

def generate_integer(level):
    score = false = i = 0  # all three are zero 
    level = int(level)
    while i != 10:       
        end = 10**level-1  
        x = random.randint(0,end)
        y = random.randint(0,end)
        answer = x + y
        while getint(x, y) != answer:  # while the user input != answer
            false += 1                 # increment false number
            if false == 3:                     # if 3 wrong answers
                print(f'{x} + {y} = {answer}') # print the answer
                false = 0                      # reset false
                break                          # end while loop
            print('EEE')               # show error
        else:
            score = score + 1  # increase score for correct answer
        i = i + 1
    print(f'score: {score}/10')
```